# prevent default not working in my javascript

Tags: jquery, show-hide, preventdefault

I have a script that I am using to hide and show different parts of a page. It's purpose is to step the user back and forth through the content when they click links. I need to keep all of this content on the same page, I can't break it into separate pages.

So far, when the page loads, I'm able to hide and show what I want for Step One and then append a link that will take the user to Step Two.

When Step Two shows and appends a link to go back to Step One, or go to Step Three, these links don't work. It appears that the prevent default action isn't working. When you click the links they go to he URL instead of showing step one or step three.

Why is my link to step two working and not my links to step one and step three?

```
stepOne.show();
    stepOneTwo.show('fast', function() {
        stepOneTwo.append( z + '<a href="#step2" style="color:white;"    id="step_2">GO TO NEXT STEP >></a></div>');
        });

            $("#step_2").click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
                 stepOne.hide(); 
                 stepOneTwo.hide(); 
                 stepTwo.toggle();
                 stepTwoTwo.show('fast', function() {
                 stepTwo.append(z + '<a href="#step1" style="color:white;" id="step_1">BACK >></a></div></br></br>' + z + '<a href="#step3" style="color:white;" id="step_3">GO TO NEXT STEP >></a></div>');
                }); 
            }); 

            $("#step_1").click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
                stepTwo.hide();
                stepTwoTwo.hide();
                stepThree.hide(); 
                stepThreeTwo.hide();
                stepThreeThree.hide();
                stepThreeFour.hide();
                stepFour.hide();
                stepFourTwo.hide();
                stepFourThree.hide();
                k.hide();
                stepOne.show();
                stepOneTwo.show('fast', function() {
                stepOneTwo.append( z + '<a href="..." style="color:white;" id="step_2">GO TO NEXT STEP >></a></div>');
                });
            });

            $("#step_3").click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
                 stepTwo.hide(); 
                 stepTwoTwo.hide(); 
                 stepThree.toggle();
                 stepThreeTwo.toggle();
                 stepThreeThree.toggle();
                 stepThreeFour.show('fast', function() {
                 stepThree.after(c + '<a href="..."       style="color:white;" id="step_2">GO BACK >></a></div> </br></br>' + c + '<a href="..." style="color:white;" id="step_6">GO TO NEXT STEP >></a></div>');                                   
                }); 
            }); 

});     
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are dynamically appending steps.

At the time of event binding the element must exist in the DOM.

If you have bound an event but then for example replace the DOM element with the event, the event is removed along with the DOM element and must be re-bound.

To not having to constantly re-bind you could bind the events using event delegation.
This will bind the event indirectly to the dynamic element through a static element.

Instead of this:

```
$("#step_2").click(function(e){ //... });
```

Use either [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with delegation or [**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), depending on your jQuery version, similar to this:

```
// when using jQuery 1.7 or later
$("body").on("click", "#step_2", function(e){ //... });

// or when using jQuery 1.6 or earlier -- note the reversal of event and target
$("body").delegate("#step_2", "click", function(e){ //... });
```

Instead of `body` you should use the closest static element which would be preferred.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. That'll teach me to type a long answer :-)

Comment: if i use "body" it should work though right? I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: @user1836025: You can also use `$(document)` if you have nothing closer. Also, make sure your code is wrapped inside a `$(document).ready(function(){//...})`, which I assumed you would have seeing your initial step one click seemed to work. If it still doesn't work then, could you check if you get any warnings/errors in the browsers console debugger? If possible could you create a fiddle on [**http://jsFiddle.net**](http://jsFiddle.net) replicating your issue? That way we could have a play-around and see what might be causing this issue.

Comment: I tried $(document) with no luck. Everything is wrapped in document.ready too.

Comment: @user1836025: That's great. I have a look at the fiddle a little later on. It could have to do with the closures but I will have a look and let you know. Edit your question and add the fiddle there too just in case someone else gets a chance to look at it before me.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: I figured it out. Turns out the version of jquery that this page was using was too old. I updated ti to the latest version and your solution started to work.

Comment: @user1836025: I was just about to post a reply. The fiddle was using jQuery 1.6 but `on` was only added in jQuery 1.7. If you must use jQuery 1.6 you need to use `delegate` instead. I updated the answer to include the syntax for completeness. Also your fiddle needs to use the `on` with delegation binding on the other buttons to as well as adding checks that if an element already exists it won't be appended again. I have a  little amended fiddle here you can use as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/L25pN/2/ It isn't fully fixed but I'm sure you can work the rest of the logic out.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Francois Wahl!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that at the time that your handler for $("#step1").click() is parsed, there is no #step1 element to bind it to - the element is created later, when #step2 is clicked.

To allow the handler to bind to an as-yet uncreated element, use on() (http://api.jquery.com/on/), binding to some nearby parent object and filtering for your link element as described in the "Direct and delegated events" section in the above link.

Assuming that your link elements are within a <div id="links"></div> (they probably aren't but you didn't give any HTML source so I'm inventing a little), you could rewrite your step 1 handler (and similarly for the others) as:

```
    $("#links").on("click", "#step_1", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        stepTwo.hide();
        stepTwoTwo.hide();
        stepThree.hide(); 
        stepThreeTwo.hide();
        stepThreeThree.hide();
        stepThreeFour.hide();
        stepFour.hide();
        stepFourTwo.hide();
        stepFourThree.hide();
        k.hide();
        stepOne.show();
        stepOneTwo.show('fast', function() {
            stepOneTwo.append( z + '<a href="..." style="color:white;" id="step_2">GO TO NEXT STEP >></a></div>');
        });
    });
```